# BindException vs MethodArgumentNotValidException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc, javabeans

I have a simple SpringMVC controller

```
@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UsersController {

  @GetMapping
  public String getAllUsers(@Valid Filter filter) throws MyCustomServiceException {
   [...]
  }
}
```

Since this endpoint has around 20 RequestParam instead of bloating the controller(s) with all the fields I have put them all nicely in a POJO (that actually can be reused in other controllers that needs similar query params filters)

```
public class UserFilter extends GenericRequestParams {
  [...] 
  @Email(message = "Hey")
  private String email;
  [...] 
}
```

Here for example I'm using `javax.validation.constraints.Email` to validate one of the fields.

However when this validation fails instead of throwing the usual `org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException` it throws a `org.springframework.validation.BindException`

Could someone explain me why ?

So fare I have already dealt with `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException` vs `org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException` (and I understood which is thrown when)
but now I also have `org.springframework.validation.BindException` that come join the party

Comment: The `MethodArgumentNotValidException` is actually a `BindException` but more specific. The `BindException` is thrown if validation fails for a complex object, the other if a specified method argument (hence the name) is not valid (like conversion fails for a date).

Comment: What is considered a `complex object` ? I'm confused because if I use the `UserFilter` class but in a `@PostMapping` endpoint and where `userFilter` is annotated with `@RequestBody` then if the email validation fails it throws a `MethodArgumentNotValidException` not a `BindException`
The same thing happens if I use an extremely simple Object (`UserFilter` with one and only email annotated field)

Comment: Anything that cannot simply be converted from a `String` to an object like a date, integer. When using `@RequestBody` there is no binding but serialization which is a different mechanism. Ah and you currently have `@Validated` on your controller which serves a different purpose entirely and doesn't use the validation available in Spring MVC but uses rather AOP to invoke a JSR-303 validator.

Comment: Ah ok! I see the difference now.
For the @Validated it's there because I was trying out things since I wanted to have `ConstraintViolationException` to be thrown